# Definition of smooth (variety)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

I don't understand the motivation for the definition of smoothness of a variety:
A variety $V(f_1,...,f_m)$ in $n$-space is smooth iff  $\mbox{rank}$ = $n-\mbox{dim} V$.

Could you please give me some motivation.

Thanks

Comment: Rank of ... what? You're missing some important things!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety.